# Access denied: no access to call this method

Tags: api, vk

I'm trying to implement VK API, so thanks OAuth code I get a token and just add this scope `offline,audio` and now doing this request:

https://api.vk.com/method/account.getInfo?access_token=XXXXX&v=5.62

And go this in return:

```
  {
  "error": {
    "error_code": 15,
    "error_msg": "Access denied: no access to call this method",
    "request_params": [
      {
        "key": "oauth",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "key": "method",
        "value": "account.getInfo"
      },
      {
        "key": "v",
        "value": "5.62"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why, there's a scope for this too?

Answer (score 5):

Your application isn't *Standalone* type or you received access token not via [Implicit Flow](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user) scheme.

**Note:** you should set parameter `redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html` to get access token without limitations. In other ways access token will be limited to call methods which available only for standalone applications.

Comment: Is there a way to make requests from a server to methods such as `newsfeed.get`?

Answer (score 1):

you also need to place
scope=messages in authorization  method

GetToken.Navigate("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id="+ VkAPI.__APPID + "&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=messages&response_type=token&v=5.87&revoke=1");